# Chart.js - How to place text outside of radar chart

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js, radar-chart

I'm using *Chart.js* to build a radar chart. I have seven datasets grouped by color as seen in the image below:

[image]

I would like to place the dataset labels outside of the chart, in the center of each dataset sector (at the crosses in the image). Does anyone know if this is possible?

Comment: Why not use the legend?

Comment: Yes, this is possible using one of the axis tick configuration callback functions.  I will send an example tonight showing you what i mean.

Comment: Thank you!! I have only been able to move all legends either to the top, bottom, left or right of the diagram, but I have not figured out how to separate them and have them positioned as in the image.

Comment: @Karonsbo can you please provide your chart.js configuration so I can recreate this chart?

Comment: I have never tried this before, hope it works! Thank you! https://jsfiddle.net/z824kyfh/2/

Comment: @Karonsbo Are you wanting to keep the labels for each axis and show additional dataset labels? Or are you trying to not show each axis label and only show the dataset labels?

Comment: @Karonsbo Also, in other words, are yiu wanting to show a chart legend but instead of the default legend look and feel (eg. boxes, on the top or bottom, etc) you want it placed around the chart near its associated data?

Comment: I see now that I might have confused the names dataset labels and legends. Your last description of the problem, i.e. place the legends around the chart, near their associated datasets, is exactly what I'm trying to achieve, while still keeping all data labels. Something like this: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwFKYyyU28xqNlNoZGVDTElDQnM/view?usp=sharing or https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwFKYyyU28xqODBueXR6Unk1TWM/view?usp=sharing

Comment: just saw your comment.  Thanks for the clarification.  Let me play around with this tomorrow and see if I can figure it out.

Comment: @jordanwillis Thank you! It is difficult to get the right placement!

Comment: Did anyone ever figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

You could probably basically accomplish this by doing roughly the following:

- Specify a non-empty label only where you'd like the group label to appear (e.g. for every sixth datapoint or something similar)
- Then set the `tooltips.callbacks.label` option to return the label for each point so that they still appear in the tooltip as they originally would